# Include raw data in C# source code

Tags: c#, .net, xna, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have an array that contains a default texture for a sprite like this:

```
uint[] bitmap = new uint[] {
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    ...
};

Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(
    GameHost.GraphicsDevice,
    (int) Math.Sqrt(bitmap.Length),
    (int) Math.Sqrt(bitmap.Length),
    false, SurfaceFormat.Color);

    texture.SetData<uint>(bitmap, 0, bitmap.Length);
```

Is there a way to include an external text file that contains the bitmap data? Or, as an alternative, I should add a resource... But how could I embed such a resource in my XNA DLL for WindowsPhone?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574307/c-sharp-read-byte-array-from-resource

Comment: Your current method is probably the most compact and efficient...

Comment: In the realm of what is possible, you could create a partial class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx. But I imagine that a resource file would be a better approach :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman ...but probably the less maintainable. Images should be embedded in the XAP as resources.

Comment: @ken2k - normally yes but this is XNA. Performance usually trumps everything.